# How to Handle SetState function in iteration in react.js

Tags: reactjs

when i use setState function in a for-loop its only assign the last value of array in every child component value.how do i make it to assign values with their corresponding index.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.postID = "";
    this.value = 0;
    this.name = "";

    this.state = {
      countersarray: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadData();
  }
  //load data as from array
  loadData = countersarray => {
    var nam = ["Haseeb", "Fawad", "Khan"];
    var elements = "";
    var count = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < nam.length; i++) {
      elements = nam[i];
      this.setState(previousState => ({
        countersarray: [
          ...previousState.countersarray,
          (countersarray = {
            key: uniqeid(),
            id: uniqeid(),
            value: 0,
            name: elements
          })
        ]
      }));
    }
  };
```

I expected output with different name but the actual output is having a same name.

State

```
countersarray:[{id:"ju2a3ex7", key:"ju2a3ex6",name:"Khan",value:0},
               {id:"ju2a3ex9",key:"ju2a3ex8",name:"Khan",value:0},
               {id:"ju2a3exb",key:"ju2a3exa",name:"Khan",value:0}]
```

Expected

```
countersarray:[{id:"ju2a3ex7", key:"ju2a3ex6",name:"Haseeb",value:0},
               {id:"ju2a3ex9",key:"ju2a3ex8",name:"Fawad",value:0},
               {id:"ju2a3exb",key:"ju2a3exa",name:"Khan",value:0}]
```

Comment: Firstly, please fix the code you've posted - why is all the leading whitespace now *backticks*? Secondly, why *do* you set the state inside the loop? You could use e.g. `nam.map(...)` to build all the new items then set them at once.

Comment: add your expected as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `setState` in `for..loop`. alternatively you can try something as

```
loadData = countersarray=>{
    var name = ["Haseeb", "Fawad", "Khan"]  
    countersarray = [...countersarray, ...name.map(nm => {
            key: uniqeid(),
            id: uniqeid(),
            value: 0,
            name: nm 
          })]

this.setState({countersarray})  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its solved by using .map function with few changes.

```
 loadData = countersarray => {
    var name = ["Haseeb", "Fawad", "Khan"];
    countersarray = [
      ...this.state.countersarray,
      ...name.map(
        nm =>
          (countersarray = {
            key: uniqeid(),
            id: uniqeid(),
            value: 0,
            name: nm
          })
      )
    ];
```